tortoise orm with fastapi pytest db
import os
import pytest
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from tortoise.contrib.test import finalizer, initializer
from tortoise import Tortoise
from main import app  # your FastAPI app

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def initialize_tests(request):
    # Set up the database URL (e.g., use an in-memory SQLite database for testing)
    db_url = os.environ.get("TORTOISE_TEST_DB", "sqlite://:memory:")

     # Initialize Tortoise ORM with the test database
    Tortoise.init(
        db_url=db_url,
        modules={"models": ["src.models"]}  # Replace with your actual models module
    )

    # Initialize the database
    initializer(["src.models"], db_url=db_url, app_label="models")

    # Finalizer to close the database connection after tests are done
    request.addfinalizer(finalizer)

@pytest.fixture
def test_client(initialize_tests):
    """Fixture to provide the FastAPI TestClient"""
    with TestClient(app) as client:
        yield client

why this is not working how to configure tortoise orm in case of testing

Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! Please edit your question woth a proper description of what is not working, what you'd expect to happen, and any errors that occur. "why is this not working" is very unclear.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
